# python function of a default argument

Tags: python, function, lambda, arguments

How can I access `qux` inside methods?  Do I really have to define it again inside the body of `foo()`, or is there a way to import it from `self`?

```
class Baz(object):

    qux = lambda x : x + '_quux'

    def foo(self, bar=qux('fred')):
        print bar

        print qux('waldo')
        # NameError: global name 'qux' is not defined

        print Baz.qux('waldo')
        # TypeError: unbound method <lambda>() must be called with Baz instance as first argument (got str instance instead)

        print Baz.qux(self, 'waldo')
        # TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

        print self.qux('waldo')
        # TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`qux` is being treated like an instance method, because that's the default handling for class members that look like functions (more specifically, `Baz.qux` has a `__get__` that is implicitly called to "bind" the first parameter to the instance, when you look it up via an instance). However, you haven't provided a `self` parameter at the start. Accordingly, `baz` gets bound to the `x` lambda parameter instead.

**There is nothing magical about the name 'self' in Python; it's just convention.** Method binding always works by binding to the first argument of a function.

You can see this for yourself, if you're clever:

```
class Baz(object):
    qux = lambda x: x + '_quux'
    def foo(self): return self.qux()

Baz().foo() # TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Baz' and 'str'
# because after binding Baz() to 'x', we get Baz() + '_quux'
```

One solution is to explicitly make `qux` a `staticmethod`, as in Sven Marnach's answer. (You can also make it a `classmethod`, which is a Python-specific concept that's more powerful; `staticmethod` more closely parallels the behaviour of the `static` keyword in languages like Java.) Note that, as in Java, you can also access the `staticmethod` as `self.qux` within `foo`. This works by replacing the normal `__get__` machinery for functions with new machinery installed by `staticmethod`.

Another solution is to provide for the `self` parameter in the lambda parameters. This is useful if you actually don't want "static" behaviour (i.e. will need to actually do something with `self`) - but it looks very much as if you do. Just for completeness, this would look like:

```
qux = lambda self, x: x + '_quux'
def foo(self):
    return self.qux('foo')
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to be able to access a method off the class then you must use [`classmethod`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#classmethod) or [`staticmethod`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#staticmethod).

```
class Baz(object):
  qux = staticmethod(lambda x : x + '_quux')
```

But [don't do that](http://dirtsimple.org/2004/12/python-is-not-java.html).

Comment: "If you're not implementing an existing XML standard for interoperability reasons, creating some kind of import/export format, or creating some kind of XML editor or processing tool, then Just Don't Do It. At all. Ever." Don't even use it for new import/export formats; JSON is much easier to work with in Python.

Comment: thank you, my actual use case was something like 
    `from os.path import expanduser;` `def foo(self, bar=expanduser('~/default'))` , can you recommend an elegant way to achieve that?

Comment: Use `bar=None` and check if `bar is None` in the method body.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use

```
qux = staticmethod(lambda x : x + '_quux')
```

and accessing it as

```
Baz.qux('waldo')
```

I would just move it out of the class.

Comment: thank you, my actual use case was something like 
    `from os.path import abspath, dirname, join, realpath, expanduser;` `psd = lambda s : realpath(join(dirname(abspath(__file__)), s))` .. but i didn't want to pollute the global namespace with all that junk.

Comment: @wim, your code is polluting the class namespace which is a whole lot worse. Just import it at module level

Comment: oh, this worked for waldo but broke it for fred .. now i get `TypeError: 'staticmethod' object is not callable` on line 5